# Perl references not returning correct values

Tags: perl, reference

this is my first time asking a question here so apologies if I am not following any conventions correctly.

I encountered a bug in some Perl code that basically lost any parameters in the URL after the first name-value pair and the solution was to use the `URI::Escape` function on the URL.

After this change I decided to move code that does this to a Perl module (Utils.pm) so that any future changes only need to be made once in this file, rather than have to update every file that uses it.

The problem I seem to have is that the user, passwd and priv variables don't seem to return the correct values - the system still allows you to sign in but it can't identify your name or the privileges that you have.

Below is a link to a pastebin of the code I believe to be relevant to the problem.

I believe it is to do with the references but any changes I make just break the page!

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate the help.

http://pastebin.com/tqGfGutW

Comment: I'm going to give you some unsolicited advice, avoid the module name Utils (and also Tools). Modules named this generically tend to attract unrelated code, and once the code is there it never moves to where it belongs. If you add one date formatting function to your Utils module when you need to add a second you will add it there to. And same with the third or the sixth. In the long run it's better to create 10 narrow scope modules with one function each, than one generic module with 10 functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to sort this out by trying a couple of things.

In Utils.pm I simply took out the backslashes so that it reads:

```
$res = CGI_ats::GetUserandPasswd($user, $passwd, $privs);
```

since these are already referenced a couple of lines prior to this, I suppose it makes sense
to not have to reference them again.

Comment: well, it makes sense to reference them again, but you get a reference to a reference.

Comment: Reference in PERL can get tricky at some point. As you gain more experience in this language, it'll get almost natural to you.